# jQuery .size() function doesn´t work with a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, console.log

At many points in my code I need to know how many `.page` classes are used.
To know this I use `$(".page").size()`
I want to save this information into a variable. 
So I wrote this:

```
var vari = { 
    *more variables*
    totalPageCount : $(".page").size()
};
```

The Problem is that `vari.totalPageCount` always gives 0 back.

With `console.log()` I get this:

```
console.log($(".page").size());    // Return 8
console.log(vari.totalPageCount);  // Return 0
```

Edit:
Here is a example how i use it.

JS:

```
var vari = {

    currentPage : 0, 
    pageAnimations : 0, 
    animationList : ".fade-in, .fade-out",
    totalPageCount : $(".page").size(),

};

var footer = {

    html : function(){
        var html;
        var date = this.date();

        for(var i=0; i<vari.totalPageCount; i++){
            html = '<span class="pageNumber" id="pageNumber">Folie:'+i+'  &#8226;  '+vari.custom["companyName"]+'  &#8226;  '+date+'</span>';
            $("#normalPage"+i).append(html);
        }

        return;
    }

};
```

HTML:

```
<body class="presWrapper">
    <div class="pageWrapper">   
        <div class="page startPage" id="startPage">
            <h2 class="mainTitle">Lorem</h2>
            <h4 class="subTitle">Ipsum</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pageWrapper">
        <div class="page normalPage" id="normalPage1">
            <div class="content">
                <p class="fade-in">HELLO WORLD</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pageWrapper">
        <div class="page endPage" id="endPage">
            <div class="content">    
                <p class="fade-out">HELLO SATURN</p>
                <p class="fade-out">HELLO WORLD</p>
                <p class="fade-in">HELLO WORLD</p>
                <p>pTag</p>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible demo?

Comment: `totalPageCount` property should be a function and FYI, you should use `length` property of jQuery set: `totalPageCount: function(){ return $('.page').length; }`  And then: `console.log(vari.totalPageCount());`. At least, what ever you are doing by manipulating the DOM, you are sure it will return the correct expected number

Comment: @A.Wolff that is a good suggestion. Please post as an answer

Comment: @A.Wolff It works but only with .size(). When I use .lenght I get an undefined.

Comment: You may need to recreate the issue on jsfiddle or codepen ... check this: https://jsfiddle.net/fLubpu1n/

Comment: @MORHERO It is `length` **not** `lenght`

Comment: @A.Wolff Oh... ok im stupid ^^ Thank you now it works.

Answer (score 4):

- `vari.totalPageCount` Gets evaluated only when it is declared.
- As a result it will only have the value of `$(".page").size()` when it is first run.

Unless you are waiting on document ready the children of `.page` have not yet been added and it has length `0`.

When you later call the console and execute the selector again - you get the true count in the console message - but the stored value has already been calculated as 0 within vari.

*length()* and *size()* are equivalent functions in jquery but size has been deprecated so length is the appropriate function to call.  But in either case - its likely you are just evaluating the length too early when the vari object is constructed for it to have a meaningful value.

Does the following give you the wrong value for the property:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var vari = {totalPageCount: $('.page').length};
     console.log(vari.totalPageCount);
});
```

[Relevant documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: I just tried this and everything I get is undefined. But with .size() it works.

Answer (score 0):

This will increment `count` for every element with having the `page` class

```
var count = 0;
$('.page').each(function() {
    count++;
});

var vari = { 
    totalPageCount: count
};
```

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nkx3dq66/1/)

Answer (score 0):

[The .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.](https://api.jquery.com/size/)

Use `length` property instead:

```
var vari = { 
    *more variables*
    totalPageCount : $(".page").length;

};
```

Also, make sure you are using this code at the bottom of the script or inside a `document` ready handler. You won't get accurate information if you try to get it before DOM has been fully setup.